# How to pass values of an array into a class Qt 5.0 C++

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I'm fairly new to Qt programming and object oriented programming, i have some C++ knowledge, mainly using micro-controllers for simple control circuits and hardware interfacing for automation systems.

I'm trying to use Qt to create a GUI to display a line drawn from x y points stored in an array, and be able to update the values in the array using a separate thread.

i currently have a very simple program drawing the lines from an array, but i cannot figure out how to pass updated values to this array from either the main.cpp, or from another thread.

i have attached my code as is below.

```
 // painterdialog.h

#ifndef PAINTERDIALOG_H
#define PAINTERDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QPainter>

namespace Ui {
class PainterDialog;
}

class PainterDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit PainterDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~PainterDialog();

private:
    Ui::PainterDialog *ui;

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e);
};

#endif // PAINTERDIALOG_H
```

main.cpp below

```
#include "painterdialog.h"
#include <QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    PainterDialog w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

painterdialog.cpp below

```
#include "painterdialog.h"
#include "ui_painterdialog.h"

PainterDialog::PainterDialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::PainterDialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

PainterDialog::~PainterDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void PainterDialog:: paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
{

    int xVal[12] = {0,1,2,4,0,5,8,0,9,10,30,9999};
    int yVal[12] = {0,1,2,5,0,7,7,0,8,20,10,9999};
    QPainter MyPainter(this);

    QPen PointPen(Qt::red);
    PointPen.setWidth(5);

    QPen LinePen(Qt::green);
    LinePen.setWidth(2);
    QPoint p1;
    QPoint p2;

    for(int x = 0; x<12 ; x++)
    {

        p1.setX(xVal[x]*10);
        p1.setY(yVal[x]*10);

        p2.setX(xVal[x+1]*10);
        p2.setY(yVal[x+1]*10);

        MyPainter.setPen(PointPen);
        MyPainter.drawPoint(p1);
        MyPainter.drawPoint(p2);

        MyPainter.setPen(LinePen);
        if(xVal[x]&&yVal[x] != 0 && xVal[x+1]&&yVal[x+1] !=0)//draw a connecting lines to points not going to the origin (infinity)
        {
            MyPainter.drawLine(p1, p2);
        }

        if(xVal[x+2]==9999)
        {
            break;
        }

    }


    QPen LinePen2(Qt::black);
    LinePen2.setStyle( Qt::DashDotLine );
    LinePen2.setWidth(3);

    MyPainter.setPen(LinePen2);
    MyPainter.drawLine(QPoint(300,100), QPoint(100,200));
}
```

I would like to use another process to update the values inside the array "xVal" and "yVal", i imagine i need to create a pointer to an array that i continually update the values, and pass the pointer the painter dialog class...

I have gone through some tutorials and spent a bit of time looking for help on various websites but have come up with nothing so far.

if anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is there a reason you are going with another process versus using a worker thread to update the values of the array while the UI thread draws them? Where are your updated x/y points coming from?

Comment: No there is no reason to use another process Vs a worker thread. 

The updated x/y points are coming from another thread that uses Ethernet communication to a 2D laser scanner which is converting the polar co-ords to X Y values to be placed into the array which the UI thread will draw.

Comment: If you need IPC - you may use QSharedMemory. But there is a problem with notifying about data changes. More heavy solution - to use QLocalSocket. But, as @Matthwe says - much pretty to place all logic in same process.

Comment: @CullodenSpectre Is the rate of points coming in from the 2D laser a known rate or can it vary quite drastically?

Comment: @Matthew the rate of points coming from the laser will vary drastically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're mixing terms 'process' and 'thread'. If you meant 'thread' then I suggest you to edit your question, because communication between threads is programmed much easier than communication between processes.

I think two main concepts in your case is [QThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qthread.html#details) class and [signal/slot](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/signalsandslots.html) mechanism. QThread is used to read x/y data via Ethernet, and signal/slot is used to notify that data is updated and should be redrawn.

```
#include <QThread>
#include <QList>
#include <QPoint>

class DataFetcher : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

signals:
    void dataChanged(QList<QPoint> data);

public slots:
    void startFetching() {
        //here you fill your data batch and pass it to PrinterDialog in GUI thread

        /*cycle over data batches*/ {
            QList<QPoint> data;

            /*cycle over point in batch*/ {
                QPoint p = ...; // take next point from your laser

                data << p;
            }

            emit dataChanged(data);
        }
    }
};
```

In main.cpp:

```
#include "painterdialog.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    PainterDialog w;

    w.show();

    DataFetcher df;
    QThread fetcherThread;

    //to execute df's slots in background thread
    df.moveToThread(&fetcherThread);

    //you'll need onDataChanged(QList<QPoint>) slot method and startDataFetching() signal in your Painter dialog

    //wire up communication
    QObject::connect(&df, &DataFetcher::dataChanged, &w, &PainterDialog::onDataChanged);
    QObject::connect(&w, PainterDialog::startDataFetching, &df, &DataFetcher::startFetching);

    //start background thread
    fetcherThread.start();

    //start GUI event loop
    return a.exec();

    //tell background thread that we are quiting
    fetcherThread.quit();
    //... and wait until background thread will finalize
    fetcherThread.join();
}
```

You don't have to worry about deleting your QList as long as you pass them around by value, not by pointer/reference. QList is actually no more than pointer with reference counting (Qt's implicit data sharing).